# How can I add page-number in pdf generated with aspose.html

Tags: c#, css, aspose

I am using ASPOSE.HTML to create PDF from HTML.
I am able to repeat the headers but unable to repeat the footer and how can we add page number in it. I am following this example [HTML to PDF](https://docs.aspose.com/display/htmlnet/HTML+to+PDF+Conversion) .
HTML snippet is as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie=edge'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900');
    body {
      margin: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
      -webkit-margin-before: 0;
      -webkit-margin-after: 0;
      -webkit-margin-start: 0;
      -webkit-margin-end: 0;
      -webkit-padding-start: 0;
      font-family: 'roboto' !important;
      width: 816px;
    }
    
    .top-abc_abc-td {
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .abc_abc1-img {
      background-color: #123664;
      height: 105px;
      margin: 8px 8px 8px 0px;
    }
    
    .col-1 {
      width: 286px;
      padding: 6px;
    }
    
    .col-2 {
      width: 202px;
      padding: 6px;
    }
    
    .col-div {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .sub-col-1 {
      width: 100px;
    }
    
    .sub-col-2 {
      width: 145px;
    }
    
    .col-3 {
      width: 286px;
      padding: 6px;
    }
    
    .col-border-right {
      border-right: 3px solid #749db6;
    }
    
    .templateabc_abc {
      background-color: #edece8;
    }
    
    p.templateabc_abcText {
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .abc {
      padding-top: 30px;
    }
    
    .abc .abc_abc {
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
      width: 774px;
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    
    .abc .description {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      width: 774px;
    }
    
    .abcText {
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .text-circle {
      background-color: #193661;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 2px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
    
    .text-tectangle {
      color: white;
      background-color: green;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 2px;
      font-size: 13px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .template-table {
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 6px;
    }
    
    .template-table td {
      text-align: left;
      vertical-align: top;
      font-size: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class='top-abc_abc-td'>
            <tr>
              <td class='top-abc_abc-td'>
                <img class='abc_abc1-img' src='WMC_logo_no_container_R-white_20170905_141629.png' alt=''>
              </td>
              <td class='top-abc_abc-td' style='width: 415px;'>
                <h2>aaaaaa Name</h2>
                <h2>aaaaaa1 Name</h2>
              </td>
              <td class='top-abc_abc-td'>
                <div style='margin: 8px'>Date</div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class='template-table'>
            <tr>
              <td class='col-1 templateabc_abc'>
                <p class='templateabc_abcText'>hjksdldasd</p>
                hjksdldasdck. hjksdldasd shown in
                <i>italics</i> are inactive.
              </td>
              <td class='col-2 templateabc_abc'>
                <p class='templateabc_abcText'>aaaaaa hjksdldasd</p>
                hjksdldasd.
              </td>
              <td class='col-3 templateabc_abc'>
                <p class='templateabc_abcText'>hjksdldasd</p>
                hjksdldasd the hjksdldasd falls in a top percentile.
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class='abc'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td class='abc_abc'>
                  <span class='abcText'>xyzA, xyz1A</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table class='template-table'>
                    <tr>
                      <td class='col-1 col-border-right'>
                        <table>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              .
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              .
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              .
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td class='col-2 col-border-right'>
                        <div class='col-div'>
                          <span class='text-circle'>hjk</span>3xyz, aaaaaa</div>
                        <div class='col-div'>
                          <span class='text-circle'>hjk</span>3xyz, aaaaaa
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class='col-3'>
                        <div class='col-div'>
                          <span class='text-tectangle'>hjk</span> 3xyz, aaaaaa
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-div'>
                          <span class='text-tectangle'>hjk</span> 3xyz, aaaaaa
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-div'>
                          <span class='text-tectangle'>hjk</span> 3xyz, aaaaaa
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class='abc'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td class='abc_abc'>
                  <span class='abcText'>xyzB, xyz1B</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table class='template-table'>
                    <tr>
                      <td class='col-1 col-border-right'>
                        <table>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              .
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              .
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              .
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class='sub-col-1'>
                              xyz, aaaaaa
                            </td>
                            <td class='sub-col-2'>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td class='col-2 col-border-right'>
                        <div class='col-div'>
                          <span class='text-circle'>hjk</span>3xyz, aaaaaa</div>
                        <div class='col-div'>
                          <span class='text-circle'>hjk</span>3xyz, aaaaaa
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class='col-3'>
                        <div class='col-div'>
                          <span class='text-tectangle'>hjk</span> 3xyz, aaaaaa
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-div'>
                          <span class='text-tectangle'>hjk</span> 3xyz, aaaaaa
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-div'>
                          <span class='text-tectangle'>hjk</span> 3xyz, aaaaaa
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class='abc'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td class='abc_abc'>
                  <span class='abcText'>xyzC, xyz1C</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class='abc'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td class='abc_abc'>
                  <span class='abcText'>xyzD, xyz1D</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class='abc'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td class='abc_abc'>
                  <span class='abcText'>xyzE, xyz1E</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I am using aspose.html for this conversion with the following code

```
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace Aspose.Html.Examples.CSharp.Conversion
{
public class HtmlToPdf
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        // ExStart:HtmlToPdf
        // The path to the documents directory.
        string dataDir = RunExamples.GetDataDir_Data();

        String InputHtml = dataDir + "input.html";
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(InputHtml))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.Write(
                @"
                    HTML code here
            ");
        }

        // File name for resultant PDF file
        string Resultant_output = dataDir + "simple-any-page_out.pdf";
        // Create PdfRendering Options object
        Aspose.Html.Rendering.Pdf.PdfRenderingOptions pdf_options = new Aspose.Html.Rendering.Pdf.PdfRenderingOptions();
        // The PageSetup also provides different properties i.e. FirstPage, LastPage, LeftPage, RightPage and they are used to setup (PageSize, Margin) for every page. 
        // In most cases, usage of setup any page is enough, but in some complicated cases, you may need to fine tune page settings. It can be done either by CSS styles or by using rendering options.
        // the size for drawing is in pixels
        pdf_options.PageSetup.AnyPage = new Aspose.Html.Drawing.Page(new Aspose.Html.Drawing.Size(816, 1344));
        pdf_options.PageSetup.AnyPage.Margin = new Aspose.Html.Drawing.Margin(20);
        // Instantiate PdfDevice object while passing PdfRenderingOptions and resultant file path as arguments
        using (Aspose.Html.Rendering.Pdf.PdfDevice pdf_device = new Aspose.Html.Rendering.Pdf.PdfDevice(pdf_options, Resultant_output))
        // Create HtmlRenderer object
        using (Aspose.Html.Rendering.HtmlRenderer renderer = new Aspose.Html.Rendering.HtmlRenderer())
        // Create HtmlDocument instance while passing path of already created HTML file
        using (Aspose.Html.HTMLDocument html_document = new Aspose.Html.HTMLDocument(InputHtml))
        {
            // Render the output using HtmlRenderer
            renderer.Render(pdf_device, html_document);
        }
        // ExEnd:HtmlToPdf           
    }
}
```

}

How can I

- Repeat footer for each page?
- Give page number to each page?

Comment: We have logged an investigation ticket with ID **HTMLNET-1251** in our issue management system to investigate repetition of footer on each page of a PDF document. Another ticket with ID **HTMLNET-1252** has been logged as a feature request to add page numbers while rendering a PDF document. We will share our findings with you as soon as the tickets are investigated. 
**PS:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @FarhanRaza Is there any update regarding the tickets HTMLNET-1251 and HTMLNET-1252 which can be helpful to me?

Comment: The tickets are pending for investigations at the moment. We will schedule them on their due turn. You will be notified as soon as these tickets will be resolved. We appreciate your patience and comprehension in this regard.

Answer (score -1):

Until the tickets **HTMLNET-1251** and **HTMLNET-1252** are investigated, you can convert an HTML file to a PDF document by using below code snippet with Aspose.PDF for .NET API.

```
HtmlLoadOptions options = new HtmlLoadOptions(dataDir);

Document document = new Document(dataDir + "HTMLToPDF.html", options);

document.Save("HTMLToPDF_out.pdf");
```

and then you can add a page number stamp to the generated PDF document by using below code snippet in your environment.

```
// Open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document(dataDir+ "PageNumberStamp.pdf");

// Create page number stamp
PageNumberStamp pageNumberStamp = new PageNumberStamp();
// Whether the stamp is background
pageNumberStamp.Background = false;
pageNumberStamp.Format = "Page # of " + pdfDocument.Pages.Count;
pageNumberStamp.BottomMargin = 10;
pageNumberStamp.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
pageNumberStamp.StartingNumber = 1;
// Set text properties
pageNumberStamp.TextState.Font = FontRepository.FindFont("Arial");
pageNumberStamp.TextState.FontSize = 14.0F;
pageNumberStamp.TextState.FontStyle = FontStyles.Bold;
pageNumberStamp.TextState.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
pageNumberStamp.TextState.ForegroundColor = Color.Aqua;

// Add stamp to particular page
pdfDocument.Pages[1].AddStamp(pageNumberStamp);

dataDir = dataDir + "PageNumberStamp_out.pdf";
// Save output document
pdfDocument.Save(dataDir);
```

You may visit below documentation articles for further information:

- [Convert HTML to PDF](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Convert+a+File+to+PDF+Format#ConvertaFiletoPDFFormat-ConvertHTMLtoPDF-ResourceLoadingCallback)
- [Add Page Number Stamp in a PDF File](https://docs.aspose.com/display/pdfnet/Adding+Stamp+in+a+PDF+file#AddingStampinaPDFfile-AddPageNumberStampinaPDFFile)